# Wordpress plugin cloak link

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Im looking for a wordpress redirection plugin that shows a message "you are now being redirected to a third party site with the website name and logo you are being direct to. Also including loading gif on the actual redirect page.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated Thanks in advance